# Random "This webpage is not available" error and AH01225: Error reading request entity data

Tags: upload, html

A script on a client website simply uploads a form and an image. However once in 5 or 10 tries the user gets a `This webpage is not available` error on Chrome. The server log shows: `AH01225: Error reading request entity data`

There is not much on Google regarding this error. The script is in PHP and the problem is not with the script. I verified this by creating a simple html form that uploads an image and the issue presents there too.

The server support recommended changing php.ini settings like increasing upload size, time etc but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're getting a timeout because of network, mod_reqtimeout settings and / or php.

Too few details though, are you using mod_php? php-fcgi? What's the status code of the failed request? Can you reproduce the problem from your computer, in which case a tcpdump may help?

Answer (score 0):

Is the server O/S Linux ? Did you check if selinux is blocking the request ?
Run (as root) :

## setenforce 0

..to disable selinux, then restart your webserver (service) and try again.